# how to extract body content from any website in plain text file using python?

Tags: python

I am new in python and i have have to extract paragraph(s) from body  of a website using python without using Api of wikipedia

Write a python script that given a URL via the command line will print a resume ( paragraph along with heading ) of the website using python std. library.
I appreciate even if any help - script will return first paragraph

- let say i call 
  $ python pagesummary.py  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Arts
  and it return some thing like below

**The Arts Portal**
The arts are a vast subdivision of culture, composed of many creative endeavors and disciplines. ........
**Featured article**
Fountain of Time is a sculpture by Lorado Taft, measuring 126 feet 10 inches (38.66 m) in length.........

Comment: lookup the `urllib` library

Comment: What do your course notes suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/beautifulsoup-4-python/) that makes use of **BeautifulSoup**. Then use your browser (Firefox with Firebug, right click and Inspect Element with Firebug) to take a look at the HTML elements that contain the text you want to include in the summary, select them via one of  BeautifulSoup `find` methods and use `get_text()` as in the tutorial's section *Extracting all the text from a page*

The text for your task is in a `div` element